# link_to with anchor renders the post and then the anchor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I use:

```
<%= link_to reply.pid, board_post_path(@board.slug, post, anchor: reply.pid) %>
```

The browser first goes to `/board.slug/post.pid` and then it goes to `/board.slug/post.pid#reply.pid` needing back button to be pressed twice to return to the previous page.

How do I fix this, and why is it happening?

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @board = Board.friendly.find(params[:board_id])
    @boards = Board.all
    @post = Post.includes(:board).where('boards.slug' => params[:board_id]).friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @board = Board.friendly.find(params[:board_id])
    @postf = Post.all
    @post = @board.posts.create(post_params)
    if @post.email.to_s == 'stay'
      @post.update_attributes(:email => nil)
      redirect_to action: "show", id: @post.id
    elsif !@post.save
      flash[:error] = @post.errors.full_messages
      redirect_to :back
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :comment, :post_file, :post_file_original_name)
  end

end
```

Comment: hi, i need to know where do you want to land after click in that `link_to` tag ?

Comment: Are you redirecting in your controller?

Comment: @PraveshKhatri `/board.slug/post.pid#reply.pid` i.e.: `/board1/20#50`

Comment: @AnthonyE no redirects anywhere

Comment: @aidiah please post your controller code

Comment: @aidiah try removing .slug in the board_post_path

Comment: @GrahamSlick updated question with controller

Comment: @GrahamSlick removed .slug still occurs

Comment: Isn't it `@post` and please also show us the view, where you have add the `link_to` tag. Its bit confusing, where the `reply.id` coming from.

Comment: @post.id? and the entire view is too big too post.

Comment: I would bear in mind that the CSS 2.1 Selectors spec does not allow identifiers that start with a digit - so having an element with `id=50` is not a great idea.